# How to access rxdart-bloc function outside of widgetTree?

Tags: flutter, dart, rxdart

I am trying to pass some data to rxdart subject. I have a streambuilder which has access to data from my products bloc. Now when I am trying to access the bloc outside of widget tree I get this error.

```
 Unhandled Exception: Bad state: Cannot add new events after calling close.
```

Here is my bloc. I want to access removeProduct function inside the bloc outside of my widgetTree (i.e. from socket event.). It is fine if subject isnot active but if subject is active I want to change the subject and rebuild streambuilder. Here's my bloc.

```
class MyProductsBloc {
  final MyProductsRepo _repository = MyProductsRepo();
  final BehaviorSubject<MyProducts> _subject = BehaviorSubject<MyProducts>();

  getMyProducts() async {
    final id = UserController.to.id;
    MyProducts response = await _repository.getProducts(id);
    _subject.sink.add(response);
  }

  removeProduct(id) async {
     if(!_subject.isClosed){
    _subject.value.data.removeWhere((element) => element.id == id);
    _subject.sink.add(_subject.value);
}
  }

  dispose() {
    _subject?.close();
  }

  BehaviorSubject<MyProducts> get subject => _subject;
}

final myProductsBloc = MyProductsBloc();
```

Edit: Is there any reason I should dispose bloc in my widget tree? Because I am not accessing multiple instance of bloc because bloc itself gives the instance, should I even dispose? I need to be able to update value preexisting in the bloc externally so I would want to keep the stream open throughout the lifecycle of the app.

Answer (score 0):

Make `MyProductsBloc` has bigger scope, such as App scope

```dart
BlocProvider<MyProductsBloc>(
    bloc: ...,
    child: MaterialApp(...)
)
```